# How do I compare empty string with ""?

Tags: string

I want to understand why

```
(when (string= issue "")
    (error "Issue number missing"))
```

doesn't throw an error when `issue` is empty, but

```
(when (= (length issue) 0)
    (error "Issue number missing"))
```

works as expected.

Documentation of `string=` states that it compares content of both strings and returns `t` when they are identical. I'm pretty sure a string of length 0 and `""` have identical contents.

The value of `issue` is set in the following code:

```
(string-match "\#\\([0-9]*\\)" text)
(setq issue (match-string 1 text))
```

I tried to replace `when` with `if` and added `(print (concat "\"" issue "\""))` to the else clause, it printed `"\"\""` as a result. I printed the POST query that uses `issue` as one of its inputs and it generated empty string in its place (the code constructing the query shouldn't even execute if `string=` returned the correct value). Not to mention that it's length is equal to 0. I'm certain that `issue` is equal to "".

Comment: `(let ((issue "")) (string= issue ""))` returns `t` for me. Are you sure `issue` is an empty string?

Comment: I'm sure it is, please see my edit.

Comment: If the match fails, then `issue` is set to `nil`, not to `""`.

Comment: `concat` turns `nil` into `""`, try printing it without `concat`, too.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew I disagree, specifics of how @string=@ works with @nil@ and @(length nil)@ equating to 0 fits the tag, since this is something that different implementations of Lisp with handle in different ways. I leave the final decision to you, but in my opinion the use of the tag was justified.

Comment: You're asking how to do something using Elisp, not something about the basic nature of Elisp vs other Lisps etc. Nearly every Emacs question is about how to do something using Elisp. There are *specific* tags for specific Elisp things (e.g. `elisp-macros`, `let-binding`, `lexical-binding`,...) - use those when appropriate. Be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty string compares correctly to an empty string:

```
(let ((issue "")) (string= issue "")) 
-> t
```

`issue` is `nil`, not empty.

```
(string= nil "")
-> nil
```

The test is misleading because `concat` stringifies `nil` to an empty string:

```
(print nil)
-> nil
(print (concat nil))
-> ""
```